# Attaching comments to blog post promoted to front page

Tags: 7, comments

I have 'blog posts' that are promoted to the front page. We would like to have the ability to have users posts comments on these posts through the front page without having to click through to get to the posts page.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do not see comment form on content promoted to front page is because by default comment form shows on full node view.So following code may help you.

```
function mymodulename_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page() && $node->type == "your_content_type") {
      $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
  } 
}
```

Comment: appreciate it. where would I place this in the modules/comment/ file?

Comment: no not there we never hack the core,this is the reason we use hooks so you should use this in your custom module

Comment: is creating a custom module the only way to accomplish this ? Have never done that before, after I create and name module, is this the only thing I would add to the code once created ?

Comment: well creating a custom module is quite simple and best way to go, I'll strongly recommend you to create custom module for this, otherwise you can do this at custom theme level also

Comment: i have gone ahead and created my first module. It appears in the module list and I have enabled it. Am I missing something else?

Comment: did you put the code and changed mymodulename in mymodulename_node_view with the actual module name and changed your_content_type with your content type name on node of which you want to have comment form

Comment: i did. I named my module front_page_posts

function front_page_posts_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page() && $node->type == "wp_blog") {
      $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
  } 
}

Comment: and you are using function mymodulename_node_view() as function front_page_posts_node_view() right?

Comment: try with this
function front_page_posts_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
      $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
  } 
}

Comment: and I am assuming you have comments opened on your content type configuration page.

Comment: attempted the new function, not working. yes comments open on content type

Comment: try clearing the cache and then check

Comment: thank you for your help but still nothing appearing